# Has Hope Summers ever mimicked a psionic power?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

Has Hope Summers of the X-Men ever imitated a psionic power? If so, what power level was it? I'm specifically asking because Hope is presumed to be the next target of the Phoenix Force that seeks out mutants with Omega Level psionic powers. If she has mimicked them it may be why she is being sought out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, several in fact.**

Hope Summers is an omega level mutant born with the powers of Empathic Power Mimicry. It is believed she has no known limitations to her powers. She can mimic powers without having to touch her target and the target is unaffected by her use of the power. In this regard her power functions like the former X-man Mimic. There does appear to be a range limit but it is suspected she will likely be able to mimic any mutant anywhere given time and experience. It is unknown if Hope's use of a mutant's powers is temporary or permanent or whether she has any control over how long she can maintain a power.

She has mimicked the powers of a wide array of mutants so in answering the question I will only list the psionic/psychic ones:

> **Telekinesis and Telepathy**: from Cable. Using telekinesis, she was able
>   to stop a bullet in midair, and she was able to sense Bishop's
>   presence using telepathy.
>
> **Psionic Exo-Armor**: from Armor. Used while battling Bastion to deflect
>   his blasts.
>
> **Telepathy**: from Emma Frost. Used to communicated while Emma was
>   trapped in her diamond form while battling the Sinister-controlled
>   Dreaming Celestial.
>
> **Cryokinesis/Thermokinesis**: from Iceman (or possibly Storm). Used while
>   battling Bastion, to create a pillar of ice and temporarily freeze
>   him.
>
> **Electrokinesis**: from Surge (or possibly Storm). Used while battling
>   Bastion.
>
> **Geokinesis**: from Magma (or possibly Rockslide). Used while battling
>   Bastion.
>
> **Telekinetic creation of biological matter and ferrous material**: from
>   Kenji Uedo. Used in Tokyo when trying to save Kenji when his powers
>   first manifest. This is also the first time Hope consciously used her
>   mutant powers.

It is likely she is being sought out, however, not just for her psychic power emulation, but because she has the power to utilize such a wide array of abilities. The Phoenix power augments the abilities of the host to an exponential degree. With Jean Grey's mental powers of telepathy and telekinesis, she was able to alter the state of matter and manipulate a wide array of energies. Hope's powers are easily the equal of Jean's at her most powerful and likely superior, making her a very suitable host for the Phoenix Force.

In Hope's body, she would likely be able to utilize EVERY power Hope has ever come in contact with and increase it exponentially in performance, range and capacity. This would make her one of the most powerful humans to have ever existed, likely more powerful than even the Jean Grey iteration of the Phoenix. And certainly the equal of almost any of the other cosmic forces in the Marvel Universe, including beings such as Galactus, The Stranger and perhaps even the Living Tribunal itself; very rare company, indeed.

If you are curious about all of the powers she has ever mimicked, check out the Marvel Wikia Entry on [Hope Summers](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hope_Summers_%28Earth-616%29).

Answer (score -2):

She has produced several psionic feats and the Phoenix Force is coming after her but it is thought that Hope is the incarnation of Jean Grey.  Even if she is not she would not be on the same level as a fully powered Jean Grey ( as the Phoenix is Jean and Jean is the Phoenix) much less be more powerful than Jean.